# How can I toggle between front and rear facing cameras?

Tags: android, android-camera

I need to toggle between front and rear facing cameras in my app. My problem is, I can open the front-facing camera, or I can open the rear-facing camera. But I can't switch what is shown in the preview once the camera is already open. As a proof of concept, I'm just trying to get my already opened rear-facing camera preview to switch to front-facing.
I'm trying to write a method toggleCamera that looks something like this:

```
public void toggleCamera(){
    mCamera.stopPreview();
    int frontCameraId = 0;
    for (int camNo = 0; camNo < Camera.getNumberOfCameras(); camNo++) {
    CameraInfo camInfo = new CameraInfo();
        Camera.getCameraInfo(camNo, camInfo);
        if (camInfo.facing==(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT)) {
            frontCameraId = camNo;
        }
    }
    mCamera.release();
    mCamera = Camera.open(frontCameraId);
    mCamera.startPreview();
    Log.d(TAG + "Restarting camera", ""+frontCameraId);
}
```

Right now, the camera just freezes when this happens. I've seen in a few places that I should set the cameraParameter "camera-id" but this hasn't worked for me, and I found no documentation supporting this.

Answer (score 1):

i just implement this with the help of [switch back/front camera on fly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6599454/switch-back-front-camera-on-fly) hope it will help you as well.

Answer (score 0):

When switching cameras, you need to set up the PreviewDisplay and PreviewListener again (as seen on this answer: [how to switch between front and back camera when using MediaRecorder android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7471025/how-to-switch-between-front-and-back-camera-when-using-mediarecorder-android/10300921#10300921)), since you are creating a new Camera object:

```
mCamera = Camera.open(frontCameraId);
// added code 
mCamera.setPreviewDisplay([reference to your SurfaceHolder object]);
mCamera.setPreviewCallback([reference to your Camera.PreviewCallback object]);
// end added code
mCamera.startPreview();
Log.d(TAG + "Restarting camera", ""+frontCameraId);
```