# How to switch between camera while recording video in android?

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, video-capture, android-mediarecorder

I am working on an app in which I want to implement video recording feature in which user can switch the camera from front to rear and vice versa (like snap chat) while recording.

I have implemented the function of switching camera, the video is getting recorded as well, but the problem is my video is getting blank/stuck from the point of switching.

I have tried with this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7471025/how-to-switch-between-front-and-back-camera-when-using-mediarecorder-android) but it is not working in my case.

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: Sample code might have helped better to understand the problem  then your words  :-)

Comment: camera preview is working, I am also able to switch the camera but the resultant video file got stuck from where I have tried to switch from front to rear and vice versa.

Comment: Have you this this feature iof switch camera on lollipop and marshmallow .I dont think it will work on latest versions.

Comment: @RonakThakkar, check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22508276/in-android-is-it-possible-to-change-camera-from-front-to-back-and-still-keep